# A simpler way of joining multiple columns to one look up table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
 TablePC

+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| PCID | Option1 | Option2 | Option3 | Option4 | Option5 | Option6 | Option7 | Option8 | Option9 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1    | JM2     | JM3     | JM4     | JM5     |         |         |         |         |         |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

and

```
 Options

+----------+---------------+----------------+
| OptionID |  Description  | ExtendedDetail |
+----------+---------------+----------------+
| JM2      | Graphics Card | ATI X1950XT    |
+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

Instead of writing something like

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM 

(SELECT * FROM TablePC) c
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Options) o
ON c.Option1 = o.Code
OR c.Option2 = o.Code
OR c.Option2 = o.Code
OR c.Option3 = o.Code
OR c.Option4 = o.Code
OR c.Option5 = o.Code
OR c.Option6 = o.Code
OR c.Option7 = o.Code
WHERE c.PCID = 1
```

Is there a cleaner,simpler way of writing this or is this acceptable? I have 12 option fields.

p.s. How does one format sql tables/results as I've seen in other questions? I had to write and indent that for code.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Normalize your data. and p.s. - that's how! I use a text editor that makes that kind of thing very easy though.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm inclined to agree but right now, the project isn't in a position to be normalised. - Before the text or indent in a text editor before going in?

Comment: Well that's the answer to a question about "a cleaner, simpler way", so the alternative answer is either "UNION" or "NO". Take your pick ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normalisation aside, you could tidy this up simply by using `IN`:

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM 

(SELECT * FROM TablePC) c
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Options) o
ON o.Code IN (c.Option1, c.Option2, c.Option3, c.Option3, c.Option4, c.Option5, c.Option6, c.Option7, c.Option8)
WHERE c.PCID = 1;
```

Also your subqueries are redundant and will hinder performance. MySQL will put the results of subqueries into temporary tables (derived tables) at the start of execution, so in a simple example:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE T.ID = 1;

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM T) T
WHERE T.ID = 1;
```

You put the entire contents of `T` into a temporary table, only to select one row from that. If you check the query plan on [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85be/2) you will see the second query is not even able to use the primary key index on `ID` to perform the filter.

As such your query should be more like:

```
SELECT Code, Description 
FROM TablePC c
    JOIN Options o
        ON o.Code IN (c.Option1, c.Option2, c.Option3, c.Option3, c.Option4, c.Option5, c.Option6, c.Option7, c.Option8)
WHERE c.PCID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 'in' :

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM 

(SELECT * FROM TablePC) c
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Options) o
ON o.Code in (c.Option1,c.Option2,c.Option3,c.Option4,c.Option5,c.Option6,c.Option7)
WHERE c.PCID = 1
```